# Ionic 2 - stop speech recognition manually on android device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, speech-to-text, ionic-native

I'm using "ionic-native" to make speech to text app. There is `stopListening()` method which works only on IOS device, But Android device automatically stops listening when user stops speaking. Is there any other way to to manually stop listening on Android?